# Apache Pig join error 2087 "Found index:0 in multiple LocalRearrange operators"

Tags: apache-pig

So I've got two relations:

- pageview counts by a GUID and URL `pv_counts`
- events by the same GUID and url `ev_counts`

I'm trying to join them with `joined_counts = JOIN ev_counts BY ev_site_guid, pv_counts BY pv_site_guid;`, but I keep getting this error:

> ERROR 2087: Unexpected problem during optimization. Found index:0 in multiple LocalRearrange operators.

I've tried using Pig 10 and Pig 11, but both return the same error.

I've Googled it, but I'm mostly just coming up with the Pig source code, but not an explanation of what it is or means. I've tried making sure I don't have any nulls or empty strings in the keys

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the schema and some sample data:

**pv_counts**

`describe pv_counts;`
{group::pv_site_guid:chararray, group::pv_hostname:chararray, pv_count:long}

`dump pv_counts;`

(bSAw-mF-0r4Q-4acwqm_6r,example-url.com,10)
(bSAw-mF-0r4Q-4acwqm_6r,sports.example-url.com,10)
(bSAw-mF-0r4Q-4acwqm_6r,opinion.example-url.com,10)
(bSAw-mF-0r4Q-4acwqm_6r,newsinfo.example-url.com,10)
(bSAw-mF-0r4Q-4acwqm_6r,lifestyle.example-url.com,10)
.... many more pageviews than events ....
(dZiLDGjsGr3O3zacn9QLBk,example-url2.com.com,10)
(dZiLDGjsGr3O3zacn9QLBk,example-url3.com,10)

**ev_counts**

`describe ev_counts;`
{group::ev_site_guid:chararray, group::ee_hostname:chararray, ev1count:long, ev2count:long, ev3count:long, ev4count:long, ev5count:long}

`dump ev_counts;`

(bSAw-mF-0r4Q-4acwqm_6r,example-url.com,29,0,0,0,0)
(bSAw-mF-0r4Q-4acwqm_6r,sports.example-url.com,7,0,0,0,0)
(bSAw-mF-0r4Q-4acwqm_6r,lifestyle.example-url.com,2,0,0,0,0)
.... not as many events as pageviews ....
(dZiLDGjsGr3O3zacn9QLBk,example-url2.com.com,0,0,37,0,0)
(dZiLDGjsGr3O3zacn9QLBk,example-url3.com,0,0,1,0,0)

I can dump the relations just fine in Pig and Grunt.

When I add the following join statement, it gets to the very end and dies:

`joined_counts = JOIN ev_counts BY ev_site_guid, pv_counts BY pv_site_guid;`
`dump joined_counts;`

It'll throw the "ERROR 2087: Unexpected problem during optimization. Found index:0 in multiple LocalRearrange operators." error and an ugly stacktrace. I'm relatively new to pig and so I've never dug into it's internals.

If anyone had any tips or things to try, I'd gladly try them. We're running on Cloudera's CDH3U3 (0.20.2).

Comment: How did you get to `ev_counts` and `pv_counts` after loading the data sets? Could you provide the full query?  I can't reproduce the error on non-Cloudera 0.10.1 by just doing a simple group on the fields you mentioned.